# How play stream MP3 from URL? (Java)

Tags: java, desktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to stream mp3 using pure Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657921/how-to-stream-mp3-using-pure-java)

I have URL, example http://mysite.ru/1.mp3.  I need play this song in desktop.

How to do this?

I know that this question asked many times, but I was not able to find the answer.   How to use the library?

update:

I need example

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to download it to a temporary `File` and use `Desktop.open(File)`.

Answer (score 0):

Java Media Framework can play mp3 files, however, I've never used it with remote files.

Comment: It is easy to convert an URL to a Stream, so if you can do it localy, you can do it remotely.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in pure Java solution then Java Media Framework can help. But if you need to install [JMF Mp3 plugin](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/download-137625.html)

Answer (score 0):

Using JMF available at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/download-137625.html, have you tried it:

```
private Player player = Manager.createPlayer(new URL("http://mysite.ru/1.mp3"));    
player.start();
```

?

Comment: I have error; Unable to handle format: mpeglayer3, 44100.0 Hz, 16-bit, Stereo, LittleEndian, Signed, 16000.0 frame rate, FrameSize=32768 bits
Failed to realize: com.sun.media.PlaybackEngine@da90c
Error: Unable to realize com.sun.media.PlaybackEngine@da90c

Comment: Have you installed the JMF correcty? Your JVM is pointing to its installation folder?

Comment: Just for sake, copy the multiplayer.jar to your jvm folder "lib", or insert into your classpath.

Comment: I have in JDK 1.6 libs jmf. How delete him?

Comment: I add multiplayer  and have error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 15
        at codecLib.mp3.k.a(Unknown Source)
        at codecLib.mp3.k.do(Unknown Source)
        at codecLib.mp3.Decoder.decode(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.media.codec.audio.mp3.JavaDecoder.process(JavaDecoder.java:323)
        at com.sun.media.BasicFilterModule.process(BasicFilterModule.java:322)
        at com.sun.media.BasicModule.connectorPushed...

Comment: I do not think you have to uninstall the libs. Have you download from here and installed: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/download-142937.html ?

Comment: Pih, I re install the libs. Not helped me.

Comment: Suggestions: try to play a simple wav file, it it plays, the problem is with the mp3 coded. Do you have only one Java Installation folder? May be you are using the wrong jvm.^

Comment: wav file - is work. Yes java folder not one. What libraries should I use?

Comment: Last try: have you installed the Java MP3 PlugIn Manual Installation: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/download-137625.html ?

Comment: I this do, but not work still

Comment: Sorry, I do not know how to help you anymore. Probably they are being installed at wrong JVM path.

Comment: Okey. You can create self-contained application and I use his.