# Playing Ogg Sound in Android

Tags: java, android, media-player, playback, ogg

In my application, I am trying to play a sound file in ogg format, stored in raw folder in res directory of my application. When I press the button that calls below function, it just freezes with the button pressed and does not respond. In the end, I have to terminate the application from Eclipse. Nothing about an error or exception in Logcat.

In debugging mode, it enters create function and never comes back. What am I doing wrong?

```
    private void playbeep()
{
    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.beep);
    mPlayer.start();
    mPlayer.release();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start and release the MediaPlayer at the same time. Try taking this out and see if it works.

```
mPlayer.release();
```

Also, check my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093157/java-playing-a-sound-effect/11093521#11093521) to make sure you have the MediaPlayer set up correctly. If all else fails, try your audio file in a different format.

Comment: Thanks. I tried removing the release() but not working. I checked your post and I am initializing it the same way. Would it change anything if I did it in the onCreate() or not?

Comment: It does not really matter if you do it in the onCreate() or not, but it sets it so that the MediaPlayer can be called anytime, rather than just (for example) when you press a button in the onClick() method.

Comment: Or... it could be that playbeep() might not have been called, and try changing private void playbeep() to public void playbeep().

Comment: No, it is being called. In the debugger, I see it going in create method, then it never comes back.

Comment: I removed release() AND used MP3 format. It works! Thank you.