# android MediaPlayer res raw folder getContentUri

Tags: android, audio, media-player, uri

I found this tutorial and am trying to implement it in my project http://www.androiddevblog.net/android/playing-audio-in-android

I want to read music from res/raw folder instead of external storage

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
```

Here is my code:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query( MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri("android.resource://com.varma.samples.musicplayer/raw/"), null, null, null, null);
```

Of course the Uri does not return anything and I want to get the audio from res/raw...

Thank you!!

---

EDIT:

Thank you both, I won't use a cursor then ;)

If it helps somebody I am using this for get all songs:

```
Field[] fields = R.raw.class.getFields();
```

Comment: check my answer here. There's no need for the use of the Cursor because you are getting the audio file from your raw file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093157/java-playing-a-sound-effect/11093521#11093521

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use a Cursor here.

Please search in the official developer docs before posting your question here. Specifically the [Media Playback](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html) page contains an example for how to do what you are trying.

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound_file_1);
mediaPlayer.start(); // no need to call prepare(); create() does that for you
```