# How to stream mp3 files with Java?

Tags: java, streaming

I have a collection of mp3 files that I'd like to send to the client in a continuous stream, one after another - something like an internet radio based on a list of mp3 files (assume the list is endless).

What is the best approach? It doesn't matter if the protocol is HTTP or RTSP (popular players support everything anyway).

Can this be done with java servlets + tomcat, or a special server like Icecast is needed?

Comment: i think this was asked before - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/657921/how-to-stream-mp3-using-pure-java

Comment: everything I've seen (including the one you linked), is about the client-side - i.e. how to consume a stream

Comment: Is http://www.red5.org helpful?

Comment: Subsonic(http://www.subsonic.org/pages/index.jsp) is a media server software. It is build on Java and is quite popular. You can check the source code (http://sourceforge.net/projects/subsonic/) what they are doing.

Comment: I forgot about this one also: PS3 media server (http://www.ps3mediaserver.org/). It is also Java-based, the code is here (https://github.com/ps3mediaserver/ps3mediaserver).

Answer (score 0):

you can use a jersey rest server exactly as its says on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14476402/1449982)

works like a charm